# will the css animation auto pause in the webview when the app is running in the background?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, webview

I found that this is not the case on my iphone(iPhonexr/13.6.1).

This is my code, just make a div move from right to left

```
.barrage-item {
  position: absolute;
  will-change: transform;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  animation-name: barrage;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
// .barrage-item:hover {
//   animation-play-state: paused;
// }
@keyframes barrage {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100vw);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-110%);
  }
}
```